# index signature of a key in an object

Tags: typescript, index-signature

i have the following typescript code

```
type MapOfErrors = Map<string, Error[]>
interface GatheredErrors {
  'dev': MapOfErrors
  'prod': MapOfErrors
  [key: string]: MapOfErrors
}

const errors: GatheredErrors = {
  dev: new Map<string, Array<Error>>(),
  prod: new Map<string, Array<Error>>()

}

 errors[ctx.env]['something'] = []
```

where ctx is of Type Context

```
interface Context {
  token: string
  env: "dev" | "prod"
}
```

I get the following error

```
src/index.ts:136:5 - error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map<string, Error[]>' has no index signature.

136     errors[ctx.env]['something'] = []
```

I'm not sure on how to add the index signature to the Map type

Comment: Can you show `ctx`'s definition?

Comment: @Jeto added the definition

Comment: @NickGinanto you are indexing into the `Map`, you should use `set`: `errors[ctx.env].set('something', [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)s don't support the index syntax like you expected they would. They are accessed using methods such as [`.has(key)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has), [`.get(key)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get), and [`.set(key, value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set):

```
errors[ctx.env].set('something', [])
```